# compile in Rails 6 Webpacker doesn't make changes to send_data with methods defined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, webpack

I recently upgraded to Rails 6 with webpack. This is when I started to notice this issue. I have a send_data method in a controller that works with either a csv or pdf (Prawn) format. Currently experiencing this issue with a csv.

In development, I made a method for `self.to_csv` in models/user.rb and used it to download some data into a CSV file. I deployed the file to my production server. And downloaded the file there.

Then I made a change to the columns that would be printed in that file. I saw the changes immediately in development. I deployed these changes to production, but still get the old columns. I checked the files on the server and they have the updates.

In Rails 5, I would see these changes immediately in production, too. Is there a way I can speed the server along here? Re-cache the files? Etc.

Here are my files.

In *controllers/users_controller.rb*:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv {
      send_data User.all.to_csv
    }
  end
end
```

In *models/user.rb*:

```
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w{first_name last_name id}

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    all.each do |obj|
      csv << [obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.id]
    end
  end
end
```

I originally had it just print first and last name to the CSV. That's what I still get in production.

And here is my deployment pipeline:

```
$ yarn install --check-files
$ rails db:migrate
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Running Rails 6.0.2.2, Webpack 4.42.0, and Ruby 2.5.5 on Passenger. Hosted by Dreamhost.

Comment: Webpack is a red herring. This has absolutely nothing to do with the assets pipeline which is not in any way involved when you send files from your rails controller. Rather this is most likely just a caching issue. `User.all.to_csv` is extremly problematic if you want this to scale at all. What if your database contains 1000s of records? You're not appling any sort of limit, sorting or paging.

Comment: Yeah I get the scalability issue, but I was just using it as a simplified example. The issue I'm really trying to figure out is how to force the browser to fetch a new cache for the send_data methods.

Comment: Do it just like you would with any other type of request. Send a 'Cache-Control: no-cache' header. Or use etags to handle cache invalidation.

Comment: You're a genius, max! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me and was thanks to max's suggestion in the comments.

I placed a `stale?` block around the `send_data` line and when I made an update it showed up instantly.

The new *controllers/users_controller.rb* looks like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv {
      if stale?(@users)
        send_data @users.to_csv
      end
    }
  end
end
```

This block came from here:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/take-control-of-your-http-caching-in-rails